# Definition of position for List ADT (singly linked list implementation)

Tags: data-structures

`Chapter 2: Basic Abstract Data Types` of the book [Data Structures and Algorithms by Aho, Hopcroft &  Ullman](https://doc.lagout.org/Alfred%20V.%20Aho%20-%20Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms.pdf#page=49) states the following:

> If the list is a1, a2, ... , an, . . . For singly-linked lists, it is
> convenient to use a definition of position that is somewhat
> different . . . Here, position i will be a pointer to the cell holding
> the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n.

There is absolutely no explanation as to why this representation of list position is "convenient".

Why not just have position i directly as the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the linked list is composed of three elements: $a$ $b$ $c$.

Suppose, we are asked to delete the second element, i.e., $b$. Then, to carry out the deletion operation it is convenient to keep the pointer to $a$ since the algorithm would need to update its $next$ pointer to $c$. Keeping the pointer at $b$ would not help update $a$'s pointer. Therefore, to manipulate the pointers pointing to $b$, and from $b$, it is always better/convenient to focus on the cell that appears before $b$, i.e., cell $a$.

Similarly, suppose you want to add an element at second position in the list , i.e., before $b$. Then, it is convenient to keep pointer at $a$ since its next pointer will be updated to the newly inserted element. Furthermore, from cell $a$, you can manipulate $b$'s pointer but not vice-versa (unless it is a doubly linked list).

In other words, when we need to manipulate some element $a_i$, we might require to make changes to the pointer pointing to it. Therefore, it is convenient to define position $i$ as the pointer to the cell before it, i.e., $a_{i-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in practice, the linked list will ve fragmented in the memory, instead of being a contiguous array.

Say, for example, you want to delete an item. Using a regular list implementation, you will need to do $O(n)$ work - since you have to "move" all elements in the list so there won't be any "gaps".

However, using a linked list, since it is not contiguous in memory - we can implement the delete operation in $O(1)$.

That being said, linked lists aren't that useful, and usually are taught as "intermidiate objects" before teaching more complex structures that build up on the idea of pointers - such as binary trees, heaps, etc.

Comment: Hi Nir Shahar, I think OP is asking why the convention of position $i$ is defined as pointer to the node storing the pointer to node $a_i$? And not simply pointer to the node storing $a_i$.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I think I understood now what the OP meant. Thanks for this clarification! I will post an answer to that shortly

Comment: Ok nvm. I don't actually think I understand what the book wanted to say there...